# JQGrid optionally editable columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid-asp.net

NOTE: I am using the [JQGrid MVC component](http://www.trirand.net/default.aspx) NOT the jquery plugin.

I have an editable column.

In some cases the user should not be able to edit it. I want to base this decision on another column value, which will be hidden.

I am aware of ClientSideEvents.AfterEditDialogShown but I'd like to do this with inline edit.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `beforeEditCell` event to disable the cell editing conditionall for the column.

**The column you want to apply conditional editing**

```
{
  cellEdit        : true,
  beforeEditCell  : function(rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
     ...
  }
}
```

To know more check [this](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing).

Comment: looks like this is not available for the JQGrid MVC component which is what my post refers to.